# What are good Unicode codepoints to test with requiring UTF-16 surrogate pairs?

Tags: java, c#, unicode, utf-16, icu

Many programming systems like ICU, Java, COM, and the CLR use UTF-16 to encode string data during processing. It is relatively difficult to expose bugs in these systems because characters in common use are inside the Basic Multilingual Plane, and as such only require one encoding unit to encode in UTF-16.

Previously I have used emoji characters, e.g. , to verify that things are working correctly; but I'm in a situation where the parser in question rejects non-alphabetic characters and as a result categorically rejects the emoji I tried to use.

What good/recognizable examples in the various Unicode categories that I can use to write good tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Deseret alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deseret_alphabet) which the Mormons developed in the 19th century is encoded outside the BMP but is made up of characters that are considered alphabetic in Unicode, and unlike some other, ancient scripts such as Ugaritic or Egyptian Hieroglyphics, Deseret is a cased script meaning that there are uppercase and lowercase variants of each letter.

[Deseret Unicode block, U+10400 - U+1044F (PDF)](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U10400.pdf)

Testing with Deseret reveals some flaws in Java's handling of Unicode. For example, `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)` where s1 and s2 are strings containing upper- and lowercase versions of the same Deseret letters returns false because the `equalsIgnoreCase` method doesn't correctly handle surrogate pairs.

**Edited to add:** I just discovered another one by looking over the [Unicode code charts](http://unicode.org/charts/): "Warang Citi", or as Wikipedia spells it, ["Varang Kshiti", the script of the Ho language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ho_language). It's a cased script for a language spoken by about a million people in India.

[Warang Citi Unicode block, U+118A0 - U+118FF (PDF)](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U118A0.pdf)

Ancient scripts that don't distinguish case are also typically outside the BMP, such as Lydian, Phoenician, and Aramaic.

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase has always been designed to compare single Java `char` values in a String. Changing it now would break its original contract, even though it would be a change for the better in terms of functionality.  On the other hand, `s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase())` will properly handle Deseret casing.

Comment: @VGR I'm aware that that works. I would just point out that the current behavior of `equalsIgnoreCase,` while it agrees with the documentation, violates the principle of least astonishment, and it is difficult to imagine any correct code that relies on the current behavior.

Comment: @David: The issue is that incorrect code that relies on the current behavior could become even less correct were it changed. I've seen lots of code that goes into infinite loops when the dev expected culture insensitive behavior but got culture sensitive. :(

Comment: @Billy I'm trying and failing to imagine code that would currently expect `equalsIgnoreCase` to return incorrect results for Desert or Warang Citi, and would break if it started doing the right thing. But I supposed a new case-insensitive comparison method could be introduced instead.

Comment: @David: Ah, good point. The cases I'm aware of are things like equals returning true when the input has different normalization forms, or where one string or the other has zero width spaces, or similar.